# AWS Elastic Beanstalk immutable updates option not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline setup to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I need immutable updates enabled for various reasons. Although for some reason the "Rolling update type - immutable" option does not appear in the drop down list the projects Configuration > Modify rolling updates and deployment settings. Is there a reason is it not appearing? Do I need to configure other settings first for the immutable updates option to be available?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As seen on the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentmgmt-updates-immutable.html), immutable update is only available for enhanced monitoring type. You can change your monitoring setting unde `Monitoring` at the config screen

[image]